# Dropbox like file navigation

Tags: jquery, dropbox

Does anyone know of any plugins for Dropbox like file explorer? Where users can sort the data in the table or select a particular row etc.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.datatables.net/ with a few plugins might help you out.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll have a look.